# No sound whatsoever. Headphones or Speakers, on an HP Pavilion dv6

Tags: installation, sound, headphones, output

I recently (3 days ago) installed ubuntu 11.10 and have spent the entire time looking for ways to activate the sound. I am completely new to ubuntu/linux and would love some help on this. I am running an hp pavilion dv6.

Comment: My dv7 has intel onboard audio which in days past was famous for the installs muted problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same computer as you. I even had the same problem with the audio playing out of the headphones and the speakers! I looked everywhere for a fix and kept coming up short in my search for an **actual solution**. I finally found it. Short answer if you have an HP Pavilion dv6-2155dx all you have to do is this.

1. In terminal type or paste:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
   ```
2. Add this line to the very bottom of the alsa-base.conf file:

   ```
   options snd-hda-intel model=hp-dv5
   ```
3. Save and restart computer.

Enjoy beautiful sound and Ubuntu!

All thanks to a post on [this website](http://www.codigovision.com/ubuntu-1004-hp-dv6-2155dx).

Answer (score -2):

first try looking in  system settings to see if the volume is set to mute! if it is not then keep reading :-)

This link is specific to your problem http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1546959 and aslo this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9664708 though the first link which is useful the problem was soleved by a fresh install! though the second succeeded with some work! and welcome to the Ubuntu club :-)